# Make wildcard function is truncating result

Tags: makefile, mingw, gnu-make, clion

I have a project that works on Mac and Emscripten and now adding Windows support. I installed Jetbrains Clion which comes bundled with MinGW. Trying to build a simple application didn't work and now debugging the makefile. For some reason wildcard seems to be truncating the filename. I checked the filenames and looked for hidden special characters but all seems ok. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?
[image]

EDIT:
Adding text in addition to image (which works fine on macOS)

```
ifeq ($(findstring _win, $(MAKECMDGOALS)), _win)
    PLATFORM := win
    APPNAME := $(subst _win,,$(MAKECMDGOALS))
    $(warning APPSRCDIR is $(APPSRCDIR))
    $(warning APPNAME is $(APPNAME))
    # gather the application files
    $(warning $(wildcard $(APPSRCDIR)/$(APPNAME)/*.c))
    APPOBJS := $(patsubst %.c, %.o, $(notdir $(filter-out   $(wildcard $(APPSRCDIR)/$(APPNAME)/*.*.c),$(wildcard $(APPSRCDIR)/$(APPNAME)/*.c))))
    $(warning APPOBJS is $(APPOBJS))
    APPOBJS += $(patsubst %.c, %.o, $(notdir $(wildcard $(APPSRCDIR)/$(APPNAME)/*.win.c)))
    $(warning APPOBJS is $(APPOBJS))
    APPOBJS := $(addprefix $(BUILDDIR)/$(APPNAME)/$(PLATFORM)/, $(APPOBJS))
    $(warning APPOBJS is $(APPOBJS))
endif
```

Comment: While the image is useful, we still [prefer text copy-pasted as text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question). The image could help to see the problem better, so keep it when you [edit] your question.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Added the text

Comment: As a first test I would try to run the makefile from a shell window to see if the truncation is really happening in the `make` process or if this is an artefact of the text output in the IDE. The usage of `wildcard` doesn't look wrong in my eyes.

Comment: It looks to me like that install of make must be buggy.  I can see no reason why you would get this and I don't recall any other report of a problem like this in the GNU make mailing lists.  I recommend reporting this to Jetbrains.

Comment: You should try doing a dir of the directory from a dos prompt to see if the file is indeed named the same as what's being shown in the IDE

Comment: Dir command shows correct file name under both DOS and PowerShell. Taking MadScientist's suggestion and have reported to Jetbrains. See what they say.